# How to override a style of a specific Joomla module?

Tags: javascript, html, css, joomla-module

I have so many modules and I am showing border to each module.

Below is what I have

```
div.ja-moduletable-inner,
div.moduletable-inner {
  background: none;
  padding: 1.5em;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}
<div id="Mod143">
    <div class="moduletable-inner clearfix"> ... </div>
</div>
<div id="Mod148">
    <div class="moduletable-inner clearfix"> ... </div>
</div>
<div id="Mod149">
    <div class="moduletable-inner clearfix"> ... </div>
</div>
```

**Note : These modules are added by-default by Joomla, so I can't handle this.** What I want is using Javascript, I want to add class in `Mod149` so that I will have it as

```
<div id="Mod149">
    <div class="moduletable-inner clearfix newMyOwnClass">`
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
</div>
```

and I will have in css as

```
div.newMyOwnClass {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
                      ^^^^^^^
}
```

Any idea how to add this class to the element inside `<div id="Mod149">` in Javascript (no jQuery!)?

Comment: Joomla usually comes with jQuery or mooTools so why not use them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 ways to approach your problem:

### 1. Pure CSS

Just increase the [specifity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) of your selector:

```css
#Mod149 > div.moduletable-inner {
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}
```

### 2. Using JavaScript

To add the class either use the `classList.add` method, or update the `className` attribute:

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('#Mod149 > .moduletable-inner');
if (elem) {
    elem.className += ' newMyOwnClass';
}
```

To insert the CSS, either inject a `<style>` tag, or use a styleSheet's [`insertRule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) method. The last method does not work when the stylesheet originates from a different origin, so I recommend the first approach:

```js
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var style = document.createElement('style');
var css = ['div.newMyOwnClass {',
           '    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.25);',
           '}'].join('\n');
head.appendChild(style);

if (style.styleSheet) {
    /* This is for IE-users.*/
    style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}
```

Comment: For today's browsers, [better use className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList).

Comment: I think you didn't read **only with div id Mod149**. I believe this will add for all modules.

Comment: @FahimParkar You already have the CSS, right? No need to add it, right?

Comment: @FahimParkar Then the HTML in your question is wrong, or you're running the code before the element is defined.

Comment: @FahimParkar If you "already have the CSS", then you do not need to use JavaScript at all - see the top of my answer.

Comment: @RobW The pure CSS solution should target `#Mod149 .moduletable-inner` not `.newMyOwnClass` otherwise he still needs to apply the class to the element

Comment: @FahimParkar Yes, go try it. If it doesn't work, then information in your question is missing (such as wrong HTML / selectors).

Comment: @RobW : Note before <div id="Mod149"> I have two div as <div><div><div id="Mod143"></div><div id="Mod149"></div></div></div>. Will this effect? I don't think so...

Comment: Went with solution 1... Perfect. :) :)

Comment: I used `#Mod149 .moduletable-inner` instead of `#Mod149 > div.moduletable-inner`

Answer (score 1):

If the element you'd like to add the class to is always the first element inside Mod149, you can do the following

```
document.getElementById("Mod149").childnodes[0].className += " newMyOwnClass";
```

Comment: No, this removes preexistant classes. Use `+= ' newClass'`.

Comment: A space is needed in the beginning of the string, or else the result will be `oldClassnewMyOwnClass`, given that the node had the class `oldClass`

Comment: Did you place the script after the element in the page? Right before the body close tag is usually  good place.